# Binary tree traversal to enumerate all permutations of Fibonacci values

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, combinatorics, fibonacci

I'm on-going working on this project as an interest, and keep coming back to it...

What I'm trying to create is an algorithm to enumerate sets of values of the binary tree of Fibonacci values:

[image: Fibonacci tree values]

The algorithm I'd use to print permutations of this tree:

1. Print root value (Result: ([root 0]=5))
2. descend to left child [left 1]
3. Print new left node [left 1], and right sibling node value (Result: ([left 1] 3,[right 1] 2))
4. If right sibling node [right 1], has child nodes, traverse this right node [right 1], enumerating it's values, along with it's sibling left node [left 1] (Result: [left 1] 3,[left 3] 1,[right 3] 1)
5. Descend to left child [left 2], as step 2
6. Print new left node value [left 2] 2, and right sibling node value [right 2] 1 of common left parent [left 1]; whilst traversing and enumerating the result of each level of right node of root. So in the about tree example, the enumerated result would be, traversing the tree to get the permutations: ([left 2] 2,[right 2] 1,[right 1] 2),([left 2] 2,[right 2] 1, [left 3] 1, [right 3] 1))
7. No left child to decend into, so stop

Each set should add up to value of root. I think my approach for trying to describe each step in the algorithm is potentially not fully clear - any help on best practice for writing out steps in an algorithm would also be useful to me.

The results I'd expect here, enumerating the tree above would be:

([root 0] 5),([left 1] 3, [right 1] 2),([left 1] 3, [left 3] 1, [right 3] 1),([left 2] 2, [right 2] 1, [right 1] 2),([left 2] 2,[right 2] 1, [left 3] 1, [right 3] 1)

I'd like to take a recursive approach and incorporate, as a method, into the Class of binary structure I've created that builds the tree. So this isn't about building the tree structure but traversing it as per the method above, or a method that yields the same results.

Could anyone help me further? Any help would be much appreciated.

## Adding in sets printing method to my `FibTree` `Class`:

### FibTree Header file (code snippets):

```
class FibTree {

public:
    class Node {
    public:
    int data;
        Node const* left;
        Node const* right;
        Node const* parent;
        int n;
        int level;
        int index;

        Node (void);

    };

    Node const* root; // 'root' pointer to constant Node
    FibTree (int);
    Node const* getRoot(void);

    void startWriteSets(Node const* root); // Write all sets of tree

private:
    static Node* buildTree( int n, int level = 0, int i = 1, Node* parent = NULL );
    // Used by startWriteSets
    void writeSets(std::vector<Node const*> &setsList, Node const* cur);
```

### FibTree CPP file (code snippets):

```
// FibTree Constructor
FibTree::FibTree(int n) {
    this->root = buildTree( n );
};

// Getters
FibTree::Node const* FibTree::getRoot(void) {
    return this->root;
}

// Write sets of tree
void FibTree::startWriteSets(Node const* root) {
    std::vector<Node const*> setsList;
    std::cout << root->data;
    writeSets(setsList, root);
}

// Private FibTree methods
FibTree::Node* FibTree::buildTree( int n, int level, int i, Node* parent ) { // Build Tree structure
    Node* thisNode = new Node();
    thisNode->n = n;
    thisNode->level = level;
    thisNode->index = i;
    thisNode->parent = parent;
    if (n < 2) {
         thisNode->left = NULL;
         thisNode->right = NULL;
         thisNode->data = n;
         return thisNode;
    } else {
         thisNode->left = buildTree( n - 1 , level + 1, i*2, thisNode );
         thisNode->right = buildTree( n - 2, level + 1, i*2+1, thisNode );
         thisNode->data = thisNode->left->data + thisNode->right->data;
         return thisNode;
    }
}

void FibTree::writeSets(std::vector<Node const*> &setsList, Node const* cur) {
    std::vector<Node const*>::iterator nodeIterator;

    // Displays all preceding left values
    for (nodeIterator = setsList.begin();
        nodeIterator != setsList.end(); nodeIterator++) {
        std::cout << *nodeIterator->data;
    }   
    std::cout << cur->left->data;
    std::cout << cur->right->data;

    setsList.push_back(cur->left);
    writeSets(setsList,cur->right);
    setsList.pop_back();
}


// FibTree Node constructor
FibTree::Node::Node()
: data( 0 ),
left( NULL ),
right( NULL ),
parent( NULL ),
n( 0 ),
level( 0 ),
index( 0 )
{
};
```

**I'm getting a compile error on `std::cout << *nodeIterator->data;` within `void FibTree::writeSets` reports:**

> _error: request for member 'data' in '* nodeIterator. __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-> with _Iterator = const FibTree::Node**, *Container = std::vector >', which is of non-class type 'const FibTree::Node*'*

Any help tracing this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Explain step 6 clearly.

Comment: @nikhil_vyas I've added some more clarity to the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm not a professional programmer, so you may have to break any suggested approach into understandable chunks. Many thanks Alex

Comment: I have edited my answer to include making of sets.

Comment: You can't traverse the nodes recursively AND output the nodes in the order you describe. What you can do is perform the traversal in two passes. Do you have any restrictions on using standard containers such as maps?

Comment: i think your tree isn't finished, or you plan to add some kind of extra search for traversal, according to algorithm (Left2 must have 2 more childs [left 4] 1, [right 4] 1), if thats correct, then i think i might have the answer for you

Comment: @Opsenas Thanks for your comment, you're correct as f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2) [left 2] should have children left=1 and right=1; likewise [left 3] should have children left=1 and right=0, but I'm not interested in the  zero

Comment: @IanThompson No I don't have any restriction on using standard containers, such as maps.

Comment: @Aumnayan I'm trying to add your code example into my Tree Class, getting a compile error; added my code here - are you able to see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Any tree can be considered as a pointer to head node. Node constructor :

`Node(int val,Node* left,Node* right)`

Tree constructor:

```
Node* Tree(int n){
    return new Node(fib(n),Tree(n-1),Tree(n-2));
}
```

This will work but will have exponential time complexity, I suggest you use dynamic programming for saving previous trees.

Now for getting set as you say they must sum up to root, For example 5 = 3 + 2. In other sets you just find ways of writing 3 and 2 as sets. for finding ways to write 3 as a set you can recursively call the same function that you call for 5.

```
vector < vector <int> > SetOfSets(Node * root){
    vector < vector <int> > leftSets = SetOfSets(root.left);
    vector < vector <int> > rightSets = SetOfSets(root.right);
    vector < vector <int> > ans;
    for(int i=0;i<leftSets.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;i<rightSets.size();j++){
            ans.push_back(leftSets[i].insert(leftSet[i].end(),rightSet[j].begin(),rightSet[j].end()));
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Add code for end cases(root.val == 1) and you are done.

Comment: Many thank Nikhil, I've already constructed the tree, I presume what this does is construct the tree. Would this return all the sets as I'd listed in the example. Sorry just trying to get my head round it. Thanks Alex

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here isn't that you need to traverse the B-Tree. This is fairly straight forward. The problem you have is that you need to keep track of the state of the other half of the equation. Aka, when you've descended into the 2nd tier of the right chain you still need to know that [left 1] = 3.

A possible solution to this is to keep track of the left nodes in a vector (or other construct). So that....

```
void start(void) {
  vector<NODE*> list;
  cout << head->val;
  visit(list, head);
}

void visit(vector<NODE*> &list, NODE *cur) {
  // Displays all preceding left values.
  for (vector<NODE*> it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); it++) {
    cout << *it->val;
  }
  cout << cur->left->val;
  cout << cur->right->val;

  list.push_back(cur->left);
  visit(list, cur->right);
  list.pop_back();
}
```

This would give you what you're looking for in the right direciton. You would need to add the appropriate safety check and the other direction, but it should get you going.

Comment: TNX. I'm having trouble trying to incorporate your above suggestion into my `Class FibTree`. In class I have `Node const* root;` `root` is passed to: `void FibTree::writeSets(std::vector<Node const*> &setsList, Node const* cur){...` **errors on** `for (std::vector<Node const*> it = setsList.begin(); it != setsList.end(); it++)`**error** _conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const FibTree::Node**, std::vector<const FibTree::Node*, std::allocator<const FibTree::Node*> > >' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<const FibTree::Node*, std::allocator<const FibTree::Node*> >' requested_

Comment: can it be got to work for `Node const* root` rather than `Node*` ? Thanks Alex

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. Shouldn't you're for loop look like.... for(vector<Node const *>::iterator it = setsList.begin()...) { ? The conversions error would seam to steam that it is a vector class of it's own.

Answer (score 0):

considering the structure of the node is:

```
struct SNode
{
    int m_iValue;
    SNode* m_psLeft;
    SNode* m_psRight;
};
```

i think the closest to what you want would be:

```
//returns true if there are still not visited children
bool Traverse(SNode* psNode, int iDepth)
{
    if(iDepth > 0)
    {
        bool bLeftRes;
        if(psNode->m_sLeft != NULL)
        {
            bLeftResult = Traverse(psNode->m_psLeft, iDepth - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            bLeftResult = false;
        }
        bool bRightRes;
        if(psNode->m_sLeft != NULL)
        {
            bRightRes =  Traverse(psNode->m_psRight, iDepth - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            bRightRes = false;
        }
        return bLeftRes || bRightRes;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d ", psNode->m_iValue);
        return psNode->m_psLeft || psNode->m_psRight;
    }
}
```

so the traversal call would look like:

```
int i = 0;
printf("(");
while(Traverse(psRoot, i))
{
    printf(")\n(");
    ++i;
}
printf(")");
```

output would be with your tree:
(5 )
(3 2 )
(2 1 1 1 )

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution, the outputs being:  (5 ) (3 2 ) (2 1 1 1 ) suggests a Level-order Breadth-first traversal, the solution I require would have an expected output as follows:  (5)(3,2)(3,1,1)(2,1,2)(2,1,1,1)  @Aumnayan suggests keeping track of the left node in a vector